# Is there anyway to detect whether a specific Opensearch search engine has been added to the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am currently working on an application that requires to check whether the Opensearch has been added.

I've successfully done the code that adds the search engine of my application to the browser via Opensearch XML file. but I wish to detect whether the search engine is currently installed or not.

Comment: Your application (except the javascript part) runs on the server and you want to check whether the search option has been added to a standard browser that supports opensearch by default?

Comment: nope, see i want to check whether my Opensearch XML has been added to the browser or not via Javascript.

Comment: wouldn't an attempted add that failed show that? (just a thought)

Comment: yeah, but i wanted a more user-friend cross browser approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really all that cross browser (which isn't that surprising, since search provider support isn't really a basic browser feature), but you can use:

```
window.external.IsSearchProviderInstalled(url);
```

Which returns:

> 0 - The specified search provider is not installed for the current user.
>
> 1 - The specified search provider is installed for the current user.
>
> 2 - The specified search provider is installed and is set as the default search provider.

Documented here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa744118%28VS.85%29.aspx. Firefox 3 seems to support it also.